# C++ Using For loop to create Doubly linked list

Tags: c++, pointers, linked-list, doubly-linked-list

I have an assignment in which I need to take an input string from a user and then populate a doubly linked list using the characters from the string. This means that I need to iterate through the users string and generate a doubly linked list. I have created a for loop and the output works but my program crashes immediately after displaying the output. I have a grand total of 2 weeks experience in C++ so please forgive my rookie mistakes. Find code below.

```
#include<cstdlib>
#include<iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

struct node {
    string data;
    node *next;
    node *prev; 
};

string getString() {
    string userString;
    cout << " Please enter a string for reversal: ";
    cin >> userString;
    return userString;  
}

// print forward
void printDataFor(node* head);
// print reverse
void printDataRev(node* tail);   

int main() {
    node* head= new node;
    node* tail= new node;
    node* n;
    string reverse = getString();
    int length = reverse.length();

    // loop to create linked list
    for (int i = 0; i < length - 1; i++) {
        if (head->prev == NULL) {
            n = new node;
            n->data = reverse[i];
            n->prev = NULL;
            head = n;
            tail = n;
        }
        else {
            n = new node;
            n->data = reverse[i];
            n->prev = tail;
            tail->next = n;
            tail = n;
        }
    }

    n = new node;
    n->data = reverse[length-1];
    n->prev = tail;
    tail->next = n;
    tail = n;
    tail->next = NULL;
    // call to print reverse
    printDataRev(tail);
}

// print forward
void printDataFor(node* head) {
    node* temp = head;
    while (temp != NULL) {
        cout << temp->data;
        temp = temp->next;
    }
}

// print reverse
void printDataRev(node* tail) {
    node* temp = tail;
    while (temp != NULL) {
        cout << temp->data;
        temp = temp->prev;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple bugs in the shown code.

```
node* head= new node;

// ...

if (head->prev == NULL) {
```

You expect that the newly constructed node will have `prev` and `next` pointers initialized to NULL.

This is a very reasonable expectation. The problem is that there's nothing in your code that will do that:

```
struct node {
    string data;
    node *next;
    node *prev;
};
```

Without an explicit constructor, `new` is not going to initialize `next` and `prev` to anything. They will be garbage, and the shown code is likely to attempt to derefence a garbage pointer at some point, leading to a crash.

You need an explicit constructor, to initialize them to NULL (or use the new syntax introduced in the current C++ standard, and declare a default initializer for both of them).

This is the first problem.

The second problem is that the main `for` loop is coded to iterate one fewer times than it needs to, for some unexplicable reason, and there's a duplicated chunk of code that inserts the last value into the linked list. I don't see any reason why this is needed. Just iterate over all characters, and insert them.

The third problem is that the logic will appear to insert an extra `head` and `tail` node in your linked list, whose data will be an empty string. This won't have any visible effects, from the looks of it, since the loop that prints the linked list will simply print an empty string. Still, that's technically wrong.

You need to adjust the logic to eliminate the duplicate, spurious nodes. Start by initializing `head` and `tail` to `NULL`, instead of a `new`, mostly useless, node:

```
node *head=NULL;
node *tail=NULL;
```

Then adjust the logic in the for-loop accordingly, to test for the edge condition of the first character in the string, which will construct a new node, with both `head` and `tail` pointing to it, and the regular execution path that inserts each subsequent character before `head`.

Comment: Another problem is that `head->prev == NULL` will always be true in initialization loop.